# remove certain sentence from document with matching pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have text document as

```
text = 'This is a follow-up to your previous request #16302 "asdkjc!!!"\n\nHello asd,\n\nSo I\'ve just received the check and a signed letter from the asc acs, .....'
```

I wanted to remove `This is a follow-up to your previous request #16302 "asdkjc!!!"` from the document.

I tried :

```
re.sub(r'this is a follow-up to your previous request #[0-9] ["](.*?)["]', " ", text)
```

This fails to remove.

Comment: Use + to signify one or more characters. `[0-9]+`

Comment: What's the point of `["]`? You should probably try testing small examples to see how regexes work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use:

```
re.sub(r'This is a follow-up to your previous request #[0-9]+ ["](.*?)["]', " ", text)
```

output:

```
" \n\nHello asd,\n\nSo I've just received the check and a signed letter from the asc acs, ....."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join(text.split('"')[2:])
```

This will split your text on double quotes & than combine the splitted text (from 2nd double quotes found in the text i.e "\n\nHello...) as a string using ''.join().